# Why do I need eval to set variable in makefile function?

Tags: makefile, gnu

If I have the following at the top of a gnu makefile:

```
$(if _,a:=1)
$(info a=$a)
```

Compilation fails (`make-3.81: *** No rule to make target '=1', needed by 'a'.  Stop.`, or `*** missing separator.  Stop.` if I exclude the colon).   I know I can get around this by using an `eval`, but I'm not understanding why it's required.   Shouldn't this expand to `a:=1`, be parsed, and set `a` to `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not understanding why it's required

Well, such is the design.

Evaluation procedure always performs a (recursive) expansion (except for "the initial evaluation" where subsequent expansion can be effectively stopped by `=`, i.e. "lazy assignment"), but expansion procedure never does evaluation, unless it's explicitly told so (basically, `$(eval ...)` is such an order to switch from expansion to evaluation).

Consider this:

```
x := 0
y := 1
# z is set to "y<space><equal><space><dollar>x"
z = y = $x

# [0] [1] [y = $x]
$(info [$x] [$y] [$(value z)])

# error as "y = $x" will not be re-evaluated
#$z

# effectively sets y to "0"
$(eval $z)

# [0] [0] [y = $x]
$(info [$x] [$y] [$(value z)])
```

From make's point of view `$(if cond,x=y)` does not differ much from `$z` --- it's expanded but not evaluated. No matter where it stands. Just think anything of a form `$(...)` to be "data", not "code".

Comment: This implies that there are different precedents for evaluating assignments and rules.   If I do `$(if _,targ:;echo $$@)` this causes the expansion -- `targ:;echo $@` to be 'evaluated', as a rule for `targ` does seem to exist after this.    (I'm assuming the proper practice is to eval the rule as well, it's just interesting that they behave differently).

Comment: @user11809993 I prefer to think of make as having 3 syntaxes at once: one for recipes (shell syntax, in fact); another for rules; and the third one for "substitution language".

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `if` function evaluates as its second argument (`a:=1`) but this is not evaluated in turn as a make variable assignment. With your version of make it becomes a rule. This is probably due to the way make syntactically parses the makefiles. It does not consider that this `if` statement can be a variable assignment because (before expansion) it looks like none of the valid make variable assignments. So the `if` statement gets expanded but it is too late for make to consider the result as a variable assignment...

Instead you can use:

```
a := $(if _,1)
```

or:

```
ifneq (_,)
a := 1
endif
```

or:

```
$(if _,$(eval a := 1))
```

or:

```
$(eval $(if _,a := 1))
```

The two last forms work because by definition the result of the expansion of the argument of the `eval` function is processed as plain make statements.

Comment: If I expand your first example: `$(if _,a,b):=$(if _,1)`, the `$(if)`'s are resolved _before_ the assignment occurs, and the the result is `a` is set to `1`.   So, for `$(if _,a:=1)` this is resolved to `a:=1`, but because the `:=` operator is in the `$(if)` statement, it doesn't seem to expand,   (I just tried `c $(if _,:=) 2`, and it indeed fails).  On the other hand, the `:` is accepted, and you can define a full rule as a parameter without an eval (in 3.81 at least).   I'm just trying to understand `eval` a bit better, and when/why it's needed.

Comment: In `$(if _,a,b):=$(if _,1)` the syntax is `something := something`, that is the syntax of an assignment. In `$(if _,a:=1)` the parser does not recognize the `something := something` pattern, so it's not an assignment. As for `eval`, it's simpler than it seems: its parameter is recursively expanded and the result instantiated, parsed and processed as a make construct. It's very useful when you want to programmatically generate make constructs with all available control structures (`if`, `foreach`,...).